# C programming nested for loop print half pyramid

Tags: c, for-loop, nested

I was having some problem when trying to print a half pyramid in C programming. The output when I set the height as 7 should be like this:

```
       1
      22
     333
    1111
   22222
  333333
 1111111
```

My code as:

```
int main()
{
int height, i, row, j;

printf("Enter the height: ");
scanf("%d", &height);

for (i = height; i >= 0; i--) //print the number of rows based on input
{
    for (row = 0; row < i-1; row++) {
        printf(" ");   // print spaces for each rows
        //Edited as I just realized that I did it in the Java way. So sorry
        /*for (j = row-1; j < row; j++) {
            printf("%d", j);
        }*/
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

I managed to print out the inverted spaces for each rows for now. But I am kinda stuck on how to print out the number for each row as the one I commented out make my exe stopped working.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `printf()`?

Comment: You don't want the `j` loop nested inside the `row` loop; you want to print the digits *after* you've printed all the spaces. And, yeah,  `printf(row)` isn't going to do anything useful.

Comment: Down voter mind to explain? I not sure for the third for loop and thats why I commented out it and the error occurs only at the third for loop that's why I never show the error message.

Comment: have you clearly read how to use printf function

Comment: downvote for 3rd printf function which is commented

Comment: But then I thought I supposed to print out the digit at the end of each row and that's why I need to nested inside the for loop?

Comment: I not sure if the logic is correct and that's why I commented out it.

Comment: i didnt downvote becuase of nesting. But becuase the use. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Comment: `printf()` is a variadic function and **must have** a format-string. Which you could easily see if you bothered to *RTFM*.

Comment: Oh wait, so sorry I forgot this was C. I did it in the Java way. So sorry about that, it's my first week for it so please bear with me.

Comment: nw delete the question. It will hamper your reputation

Comment: I modified it by emphasizing the comments there. Sorry for the mistakes!

Comment: @Denise hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple question and the correct code for this is:

```
int main()
{
int height, i, row, j,no=1;    
printf("Enter the height: ");
scanf("%d", &height);    
for (i = height; i > 0; i--) //print the number of rows based on input
{
    if(no>3)
        no=1;//so that numbers never exceed 3
    for (row = 0; row < i-1; row++)
        printf(" ");   // print spaces for each rows    
    for(j=height+1;j>i;--j)
        printf("%d",no);//print the numbers
    no++;
    printf("\n");
}    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But do you mind to explain a little bit on the third for loop? I get confused.

Comment: @Denise Reason why j has height+1 as initial value is because i has height as initial value, so it is clear, only 1 number will be printed in first case, when we come to the same loop second time, i must have decremented by 1 which means the third loop will now run from height+1 to height that is 2 times which is what we want and rest is easy to see.

Comment: I see I see. Thanks a lot for the helps!

Answer (score 2):

Catch!:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): " );

        unsigned int n = 0;
        scanf( "%u", &n );

        if ( !n ) break;

        printf( "\n" );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            const unsigned int k = i % 3 + 1;
            printf( "%*d", n - i, k );
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) printf( "%d", k );
            printf( "\n" );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }        
}
```

If to enter sequantially

```
10 7 0
```

the the output will be

```
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 10

         1
        22
       333
      1111
     22222
    333333
   1111111
  22222222
 333333333
1111111111

Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 7

      1
     22
    333
   1111
  22222
 333333
1111111

Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 0
```

Comment: Hi so sorry but what does this line do? printf( "%*d", n - i, k ); From what I understand is in the first loop which you getting the user input, you are getting modules and assigned it to k. Then for the for loop with j, you are displaying the k.

Comment: @Denise  It outputs n - i - 1 blanks without using a loop and outputs the digit.

Comment: So basically the *d did the magic for the spacing and mod? Because I tried to remove the * and the results returned are different. Would you mind to explain what the * does?

Comment: @Denise * allows to specify the length of the outputed field using  a variable that stores the required value and passed to printf as an argument.

Comment: @Denise  It is the best code among presented here.:)

Comment: Yeah haha thanks a lot! Reverse for loop is giving me a headache :)

Answer (score 1):

Your commented for-loop should not be nested, you just need to take the value of `i` and go from there up to `height`.

Also, the condition in the top level for-loop should be `i > 0`.

```
int main()
{
    int height, i, row, j;

    printf("Enter the height: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    for (i = height; i > 0; i--) //print the number of rows based on input
    {
        for (row = 0; row < i; row++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (j = i; j <= height; j++) {
            printf("%d", (height - i) % 3 + 1);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Enter the height: 7
       1
      22
     333
    1111
   22222
  333333
 1111111
```

Comment: @Denise No problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int width = 7;
    int height = 7;
    int b = 3;

    for(i = 1; height >= i; ++i) {
        for(j = 1; width >= j; ++j) {
            if(width - i < j) {
                int x = (i % b);
                printf("%d", x ? x : b);
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alright thanks a lot! Yours works too but a little bit complicated

Answer (score 0):

Just to show that you could use the width argument in `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int height, j, n = 0;

    printf("Enter the height: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    for (j = 0; j < height; n *= 10)
    {
        printf("%*d\n", height+1, ++n * (1 + j++ % 3));
    }

    return 0;
}
```